# Redux toolkit dispatch action with dispatch and getState as arguments, same as simple redux implementation with function enhancer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been using simple redux with this function enhancer for a long time :

```js
const asyncFunctionMiddleware = storeAPI => next => action => {
  // If the "action" is actually a function instead...
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    // then call the function and pass `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments
    return action(storeAPI.dispatch, storeAPI.getState)
  }

  // Otherwise, it's a normal action - send it onwards
  return next(action)
}
```

Once this was added to applyMiddleware at time of store create you can simply use it as this :

```js
// Write a function that has `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments
const stateBasedLotOfDispatches = (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Lot of conditions based on current state -> getState
  // get arguments to pass to action1
  // create payload for action2
  dispatch(action1())
  dispatch(action2())
  ...
}
```

I searched a lot about how to do this with redux toolkit, but could not find a way or maybe missing something basic about redux-toolkit and will like someone to point me in the right direction.

Need to add 1 more thing, function called will not be asyncThunk type so i don't need it to be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is literally the `redux-thunk` middleware, and that one is already enabled automatically with Redux Toolkit.

You can just go ahead and `dispatch(stateBasedLotOfDispatches)` and it will work.

Comment: Do i need to add thunk into configureStore or is it enabled out of the box in toolkit ?

Comment: I literally wrote that it is automatically enabled. So yes. It is enabled out of the box ;)

Comment: I finally found the issue was i was calling ```dispatch(stateBasedLotOfDispatches())``` instead of ```dispatch(stateBasedLotOfDispatches)```.
Thanks that cleared up a lot of stuff.

Comment: Yeah, you have written a thunk that's a bit unusual there.